# React application rendering issue in Iphone/MAC(Safari browser) after react app build

Tags: reactjs, react-native

We are facing below error while rendering react application in Safari browser in IOS and Mac only. The application is working fine on other operation systems and browsers like Firefox and chrome.
I have attached the browser console error log in the image. Please check and any poiner on this will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8sC9.jpg)

We just simply try to build the react application and expecting to run on safari browser as well like Chrome and Firefox

```js
Console cleared at 12:07:47
Error: Minified React error #299; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=299 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings. f (anonymous function) index.js:2:180944
f (anonymous function)-index.js:2:199026
f (anonymous function)-index.js:2:200328
S Global Code index.js:2:200331
MacBook Pro
```

Comment: The image doesn't seem to have been attached. Though, a better practice is copy-paste the logs as plaintext and add it to your question, so it can help other people search for the same issue.